# Jsx Component not showing after conditional checks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The problem is I have two redux stores

1. `items(Items Store`
2. `quotationItems(Quote Items`.

When a product item is added to `quotationItems` I Would to show `<RedButton title="Remove" />` or when the `quotationItems` is empty the `<AddButton title="Add" />` should be shown.

using `if` statement tends to re-render the component and adds new components e.g: After adding a new product to quotation items, there will be a new `<AddButton />` in FlatList Component.

```js
interface IProps {
  items: ItemInterface[];
  documentItems: ItemInterface[];
  onAddItem: any;
}

const ItemFlatList2: FC<Partial<IProps>> = ({
  items,
  documentItems,
  onAddItem,
}) => {
  const TestView = (itemCode) => {
    documentItems.map((x) => {});
  };
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={items}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.itemCode.toString()}
      renderItem={({
        item: { itemCode, itemDescription, itemSellingPrice },
      }) => {
        return (
          <div className={styles.itemContainer}>
            <h4>Item Code: {itemCode}</h4>
            <h4>Description: {itemDescription}</h4>
            <div>
              {documentItems.map((x) => {
                x.itemCode === itemCode ? (
                  <RedButton title={"Remove"} key={itemCode} />
                ) : (
                  <AddButton title={"Add"} key={itemCode} />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Other options I've tried:

I've also tried this, still doesn't work, the buttons will show up but after clicking on the first button, which will successful add the `product item` to `quotation item` store but when I try and click on the 2nd or 3rd button of `<AddButton title={'Add'} key={itemCode} /> I get no response.

```js
            <div>
              {documentItems.length <= 0 ? (
                <AddButton
                  title={"Add"}
                  key={itemCode}
                  onClick={() => onAddItem(itemCode)}
                />
              ) : (
                documentItems!.map((x) =>
                  x.itemCode === itemCode ? (
                    <RedButton title={"Remove"} key={itemCode} />
                  ) : (
                    <
AddButton title={"Add"} key={itemCode} onClick={() => onAddItem(itemCode)} />
                  )
                )
              )}
            </div>
```

This is the result of the modified code above:
[image: Result of Modified Code]

Answer (score 0):

Please add the return keyword.

```
documentItems.map((x) => {
return (x.itemCode === itemCode ? (
<RedButton title={"Remove"} key={itemCode} />
) : (
<AddButton title={"Add"} key={itemCode} />
);
)})
```

Or Just remove the curly braces.

```
documentItems.map((x) => (x.itemCode === itemCode ? (
<RedButton title={"Remove"} key={itemCode} />
) : (
<AddButton title={"Add"} key={itemCode} />
)))
```

Based on the updations that you did in the questions. It is an issue with the data in "documentItems". Since you only need 1 button per item code. Instead of map use find. It will return 1 item and fix this duplicacy.

Comment: Both of your solutions did not work. The buttons are not showing up for some reason.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this code adds the buttons and now you are concerned about click event binding. correct?

Comment: just add the onclick handler

Comment: I will edit the question to show the results of those actions.

Comment: that would be great

Comment: I've edited the question again, please have a look at the gif result of the modified code.

Comment: use find instead of map.